# gpg2 won't import .key files : No valid OpenPGP data found

Tags: gpg

I want to import my old gpg2 secret keyring from a backup. I only have my old `.gnupg` directory.

But all files in this folder are unrecognized by gpg2, which says "No valid OpenPGP data found" when I try to `--import` them.

How can I import my old secret keys ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved it by replacing my new `.gnupg` directory by the old one, exporting the keys in an importable format, then restoring my new `.gnupg` and importing the keys :

```
mv ~/.gnupg ~/.new_gnupg
cp -r old_backup/.gnupg ~
gpg2 --export-secret-keys > sec.gpg
rm -r ~/.gnupg
mv ~/.new_gnupg ~/.gnupg
gpg2 --import sec.gpg
```